# How to use Mock Functions in React JS using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a function using: [Facebook's Jest Mock Functions](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html)

However, I get this error:

```
 jest.mock is not a function

    TypeError: jest.mock is not a function
        at evaluate (https://oq7kwzrnj5.codesandbox.io/src/ListItem.spec.js:21:6)
        at r.a (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.f3fc5e5b.js:5354:971)
        at e.value (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.f3fc5e5b.js:5413:270)
        at e.value (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.f3fc5e5b.js:5386:23195)
        at e.value (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.f3fc5e5b.js:5386:22974)
        at e. (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.f3fc5e5b.js:5386:18687)
        at n (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:2847:811)
        at Generator._invoke (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:2847:599)
        at Generator.e.(anonymous function) [as next] (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:2847:990)
        at o (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:3049:316)
        at https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:3049:464
        at new Promise ()
        at new t (https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:678:776)
        at https://codesandbox.io/static/js/common-sandbox.5c75aa32.js:3049:258
        at https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.f3fc5e5b.js:5386:18996
        at Array.map ()
```

Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

Could someone please help me to resolve this error?

any update

Comment: Could you post your code in some repo so I can run it locally?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk it is present https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk from morning I tried different ways but not suceed here is my updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

Comment: @user5711656 maybe it's something with codesandbox, that prevent code from running properly. That's why it'll be helpful to have your projest run locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock your function like this ***mockMyFunc = jest.fn()***

Also checkout my answer to this question:
[why actual and expected length is not equal in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829698/why-actual-and-expected-length-is-not-equal-in-react-js/49830608#49830608)