# why actual and expected length is not equal in react js

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, enzyme

could you please tell me why actual and expected  length is not equal in react js 
here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
mockAxios.get.mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          data: ['a','b']
        }
      }));
```

I am sending `2` elements on array but getting `0` element

```
it("axios call check or not", async () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<List />);
      expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

      expect(wrapper.find("li").length).toBe(2);

    });
```

[image]

Comment: Your coding sandbox is not showing the example.

Comment: The issue maybe relates to the component lifecycle.

Comment: showing https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

Comment: i thing not related to life cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making **async** call in ComponentDidMount. Async means 'do not wait', so using wrapper.debug(), you can see that it contains no **li** tag since initial state of items is [], once call is done, it updates the state and re-renders the DOM.

And wrapper in the enzyme is immutable. So you can update the state in your test case, and then check for the **li** tag length in the wrapper. Also, I would advise making an async call in ComponentWillMount, for your use case.
The way you mocked API and the response doesn't make sense to me, have used "axios-mock-adapter" which was already present in package.json. :)

Here is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/30jp9vk67q

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import List from "./ListItem";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

describe("List Components", () => {
  var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  beforeEach(() => {
    mock
     .onGet("https://biz.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/bankifsc/getlist")
      .reply(200, {
        data: [{ text_val: "a" }, { text_val: "b" }]
      });
  });

  describe("List Items", () => {
    it("check length", () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<List />);
      console.log("Wrapper-Before-", wrapper.debug());
      wrapper.setState({ items: [{ text_val: "a" }, { text_val: "b"}]})
      console.log("Wrapper-After-", wrapper.debug());
      expect(wrapper.find("li").length).toBe(2);
    });
  });
});
```